# How to align image button right under imageview which is at the top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Here my whole xml file. I can not align image button at the bottom of imageview i have at the top

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Pokemon$PlaceholderFragment"
style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/monstermmorpg_android_bg">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/application_text"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/image_button"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
 />
```

This is how it is displayed : i want it to be under imageview which is displayed at the top

Thank you very much i am using android studio latest on windows 8.1 - android version 2.3 api 9

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
```

to the ImageButton.